# Traversing a JSON file to use in a chart

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a result coming from my database in the following JSON format;

```
[
{"Labels":"one","Array":"[\"49.0\",\"60.0\",\"91.0\",\"55.0\",\"46.0\"]"},
{"Labels":"two","Array":"[\"7.6\",\"10.3\",\"12.8\",\"9.3\",\"7.5\"]"},
{"Labels":"three","Array":"[\"11.8\",\"10.6\",\"27.5\",\"11.2\",\"10.8\"]"},
{"Labels":"Labels","Array":"[\"3XYUP\",\"3XYMC\",\"3XLLM\",\"3XPTY\",\"3XMMM\"]"}
]
```

What I want to do is select a specific array and set it as a variable in JQuery.

I can't find a way to get the Array for Label "one".

The end goal is to have a chart.js chart using the bottom row as the labels and one of the other rows as the data property.

Help?!

Comment: The array for labels one is `whateverVariable[0].Array`.  You have an array of objects, of which the `Array` key in each object contains a string value.

Comment: This isn't really a jQuery question though.  It's a javascript question.

Comment: Can you show how you created the JSON in PHP? You could probably make it easier to access if you could restructure it a bit (like use "one", "two", "three" as keys instead of values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions Taplar and Don't Panic.

The solution that I've gone with after a couple of hours of trying to get this to work is as follows;

```
  $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'queries.php',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
  for (var index in data) {
  console.log( data[1]["Array"] );
  console.log( data[2]["Array"] );
  console.log( data[3]["Array"] );
}
  }
});
```

This allows me to access each part of the array and set the values in to variables.

Thanks for your time anyway - I'm finding more and more than gathering other ideas simply points me in the direction I need.